# Message: Undefined property: classname::$navbardata, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following in my codeigniter constructor:

```
$navbar= new stdClass(); 
$navbar->user_email = $this->user_email;
$navbar->vp = $this->vp;
```

When I try to access this in my index function:

```
public function index() {

     var_dump($this->navbar);
```

I get :

```
Message: Undefined property: classname::$navbar
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: Try in the bottom: `$this->navbardata = $navbardata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$navbardata` needs to be made available to the Buyers object to be available to a method via `$this`

Ways that this can be accomplished.

Injection through the constructor

```
 class Buyers {
    protected $navbardata;
    public function __construct($nbd){
         $this->navbardata = $nbd;
    }
 }
```

Setter Injection

```
 class Buyers{
    protected $navbardata;
    ....
    public function setNavBarData($nbd){
          $this->navbardata  = $nbd;
    }
```

Or via a public property

```
  class Buyers {
      public $navbardata;
      ....
  }

  $b = new Buyers();
  $b->navbardata = $navbardata
```